# How to run an if statement inside of an append statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to run an if statement inside of an append but it seems to come out as true regardless of what I expect the result to be. The problematic code is on lines 13 and 14, Code:

I've tried declaring it using the typical method of...
   if(xxx != "false") but this broke the entire page and no JS ran.

```
 $.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Fazyyy/Fazyyy.github.io/master/data/product.json", function(posts) {
  for(var post = 0; post < posts.length; post++) {
   $(".posts").append("<li " + 
    "data-price='"+ posts[post].price + "'" +
    "data-reviews='"+ posts[post].reviews + "'" +
    "data-name='"+ posts[post].name + "'" +
    "data-saving='"+ posts[post].was_price + "'" +
    ">" +
    "<div class='spacer'>" +
    "<img src='./img/" + posts[post].img +".jpg' />" +
    "<h2>" + posts[post].name + "</h2>" +
    "<p>" + "£<span class='price'>" + posts[post].price + "</span></p>" +
    ( posts[post].was_price != "false" ? "<p class='red'>£<span     class='strike'>" + posts[post].was_price + "</span></p>" : '<p></p>') +
    ( posts[post].reviews != "false" ? "<p class='reviews'>" +     posts[post].reviews + "% reviews score" : '<p></p>') +
    "<p><a href='#' class='basket'>Add To Basket</a></p>" + "</div>" +     "</li>"
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Simple answer: don't. Build your HTML outside of the `append()`, then call the function with the finalised string. If you really did want to do this you could use a ternary but I'd advise against it as it turns in to a hard to read mess. In fact, given the large string of HTML you have in the question I'd strongly suggest you look in to using a template for this instead.

Comment: Did you try console logging the conditionals outside of the append?  Maybe you have a logic problem

Comment: If `posts[post].was_price` is a boolean value, then whether it's `true` or `false` it will be not equal to the **string** `"false"`

Comment: `false === "false"` equals false,  and `false == "false"` equals false.  IOW: "false" is never false no matter how you compare it to `false`.. :)

Comment: Just to clarify, in the json the value is actually the string" false. What I'm trying to do is check that it is something other than "false" and then print out xxx but if it IS "false" then I print a blank <p> tag.

Comment: also the was_price is the price of something in the past, it may be 7.99 for example. But if it's not been reduced it's "false".

Comment: I just noticed your reviews ternary is missing a closing p tag for the true case

Comment: Updated the source thank you, although as expected it's not had any affect on the primary issue.

Comment: @JaimieWarburton has my answer resolved your issue if you have any questions let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer is don't.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

you should abstract your problems following the DRY principles 'dont repeat yourself' and focus on making it easy to read and everything just has one responsibility.

you can see in my example that it almost looks like it would in html but in your example you have to struggle to parse the logic.

Another few things to note was you were doing something != 'false' where you had to do != instead of !== because you were comparing 'false' to false. read up on type equality

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

```js
$.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Fazyyy/Fazyyy.github.io/master/data/product.json", function(posts = []) {
  // appending only after we've created all posts to stop appending multiple times
  appendToPosts(posts.reduce((acc, post) => acc + createPost(post), ''))
});

function appendToPosts(html) {
  $(".posts").append(html);
}


function createPost(post) {
  return `<li
            data-price='${post.price}' 
            data-reviews='${post.reviews}'
            data-name='${post.name}'
            data-saving='${post.was_price}'>
              <div class='spacer'>
                <img src='./img/${post.img}.jpg' />
                <h2>${post.name}</h2>
                <p>£<span class='price'>${post.price}</span></p>
                ${hasPreviousPrice(post)}
                ${hasReviews(post)}
              </div>
         </li>`;
}

function hasPreviousPrice(post) {
  return post.was_price ?
    `<p class='red'>£<span class='strike'>${post.was_price}</span></p>` :
    ``
}

function hasReviews(post) {
  return post.reviews ?
    `<p class='reviews'>${post.reviews}% reviews score` :
    `<p><a href='#' class='basket'>Add To Basket</a></p>`
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="posts"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach. This one does not `append` multiple times, as it's a more expensive operation.

```
const productTmpl = ({was_price, reviews, price, name, img}) => {
  const wasPriceNode = was_price
    ? `<p class="red">£<span class="strike">${was_price}</span></p>` 
    : "<p></p>"
  const reviewsNode = reviews
    ? `<p class="reviews">${reviews}% reviews score</p>` 
    : "<p></p>"

  return `
    <li data-price="${price}"
      data-reviews="${reviews}"
      data-name="${name}"
      data-saving="${was_price}"
    > 
      <div class="spacer'">
        <img src="./img/${img}.jpg"/>
        <h2>${name}</h2>
        <p>£<span class="price">${price}</span></p>
        ${wasPriceNode}
        ${reviewsNode}
        <p>
          <a href="#" class="basket">Add To Basket</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
  `;
}

$.getJSON(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Fazyyy/Fazyyy.github.io/master/data/product.json",
  products => {
   const listItems = products.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + productTmpl(cur), "");
   $(".posts").html(listItems);
  }
);
```

Comment: very good point and nice approach :) about appending multiple times, i've adjusted my answer to reflect this. luckly due to my approach it was just moving the appending function around the loop rather than in.

Comment: @JoeWarner Your solution and explanations are very nice as well.